# Mongo DB aggregation to sort by array field, select first three records and merge other records as one

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a collection which has array of cars like below:

```
cars:[
    {
        "manufacturer": "Skoda",
        "numbersSold": 40
    },
    {
        "manufacturer": "Hyundai",
        "numbersSold": 90
    },
    {
        "manufacturer": "Maruti",
        "numbersSold": 400
    },
    {
        "manufacturer": "VW",
        "numbersSold": 15
    },
    {
        "manufacturer": "Mercedez Benz",
        "numbersSold": 1
    }
]
```

is it possible to run aggregation on this collection to produce below result:

```
cars:[
    {
        "manufacturer": "Maruti",
        "numbersSold": 400
    },
    {
        "manufacturer": "Hyundai",
        "numbersSold": 90
    },
    {
        "manufacturer": "Skoda",
        "numbersSold": 40
    },
    {
        "manufacturer": "Other",
        "numbersSold": 16
    }
]
```

That is top 3 manufacturers with most numbersSold and 4th record should be displayed as "others" with combined value of "numbersSold" for "VW" and "Mercedez Benz" i.e, 15+1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve that in 5 steps/stages using [aggregation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/), Try this below query :

```
db.cars.aggregate([

    /** Remove _id field in cars collection, which also reduces size of doc a bit by removing a field across all docs */
    { $project: { _id: 0 } },

    /** Sort to get top manufacturers */
    { $sort: { numbersSold: -1 } },

    /** group to push all manufacturers into an array */
    { $group: { _id: '', cars: { $push: '$$ROOT' } } },

    /** project to seperate top 3 manufacturers & others */
    {
        $project: {
            _id: 0, others: [{
                $reduce: {
                    input: { $slice: ["$cars", 3, { $size: '$cars' }] },
                    initialValue: { numbersSold: 0 },
                    in: { "manufacturer": 'Other', numbersSold: { $add: ["$$value.numbersSold", "$$this.numbersSold"] } }
                }
            }], cars: { $slice: ["$cars", 3] }
        }
    },

    /** project to merge top 3 manufacturers & others into one array named cars */
    { $project: { cars: { $concatArrays: ['$cars', '$others'] } } }])
```

**Test :** [MongoDB-Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Np55Mu8BNck)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [aggreagation framework](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/aggregation/) to achieve this.

Here's the query :

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $sort: {
      "numbersSold": -1
    }
  },
  {
    $facet: {
      bestThree: [
        {
          $limit: 3
        }
      ],
      others: [
        {
          $skip: 3
        },
        {
          $addFields: {
            manufacturer: "others"
          }
        },
        {
          $group: {
            _id: null,
            manufacturer: {
              $first: "$manufacturer"
            },
            numbersSold: {
              $sum: "$numbersSold"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      result: {
        $concatArrays: [
          "$bestThree",
          "$others"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$result"
  },
  {
    $replaceRoot: {
      newRoot: "$result"
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0
    }
  }
])
```

After [$sort](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/) stage, use [$facet](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/facet/) to get your 3 best results on one hand, and the others on the other hand, group these and calculate sum.
The last stages after facet are just here to format your documents to your desired output.

You can test it [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/oLfO56exLrR)